# __range django isn't working

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have __range that looks like this:

```
backwards = str(distance-10).split('.')[0]
frontwards = str(distance+10).split('.')[0]
route = Route.objects.filter(miles_from_warehouse__range=(backwards,frontwards))
```

backwards can be an integer simple as 6
and frontwards can be 26;
I want data everything within range of 6-26
however it gives me nothing, but instead when I use 0 instead of 6; it gives me it. How come?

```
miles_from_warehouse = models.CharField(max_length=120,default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Your `miles_from_warehouse` field is a `CharField`... I don't think integer range queries will work on that. You probably need to think about using a float or integer field instead.

Comment: How come it worked; when I tried it with 0, 26?

Comment: Because when you do `range` on a CharField it will find all *alphanumeric characters* within that range. This is not the same as integer values.

Comment: After I used FloatField; everytime I run python manage.py migrate it gives me  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1760, in get_prep_value
    return float(value)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: Well that is because you must have values in your database that cannot be converted to a float! Most probably `null` values in which case you need to set `null=True` on the float field.

Comment: miles_from_warehouse = models.FloatField(null=True)
I then do manage.py makemigrations, then manage.py migrate
Same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169009/discussion-between-zennn-and-solarissmoke).